# Gap in evidence of work experience

Tags: australia, pr

I worked in a small company for 2 years after my studies, but I don't have any payslips or bank statement as I was getting the salary as cash. Only thing I am having is an experience certificate.

I am from India. The salary I got was less than the tax threshold, so I didn't have to pay tax. Also, the company is closed very soon after I left.

I want to apply for a Skilled PR Visa to Australia. But, I am not sure whether or not to mention this work experience as its lack of strong evidence.

1. If I mention the work experience, the application may refuse due to lack of evidence? (I didn't mention that work experience with the next employers as they suggested. They said that it may make a problem in background verification as the company was closed)
2. If I don't mention, there would be 2 years of gap in work experience. Do I need to bother about this?